# CORS error appears when I Upload multiple files at once to S3 Bucket with boto3

Tags: python, reactjs, django, amazon-s3, upload

I have a question about S3 upload, I use `boto3` library in `python` to connect to S3.

```
def get_client():
return boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id = 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY',
        aws_secret_access_key = 'AWS_SECRET_KEY')
```

My Multiple upload file in below

```
for item in img_files:
            file_type = ''
            uuid_key = uuid.uuid4()
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(f'{S3_TEMP_FOLDER}{uuid_key}-{item.name}', item)
            file_o_name, file_o_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
            if file_o_ext.lower() in ['.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg']:
                file_type = 'image'
            else:
                file_type = 'video'

            uploaded_file_path = fs.path(filename)
            
            try:
                s3_client.upload_file(uploaded_file_path, bucket_name, f'{folder_key}/{uuid_key}-{item.name}', ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read'})
                uploaded_data = {
                    "file_name": item.name,
                    "file_key": f'{folder_key}/{uuid_key}-{item.name}',
                    "bucket_name": bucket_name,
                    "folder_id": get_folder_id.id,
                    "created_by": request.user.username,
                    "updated_by": request.user.username,
                    "bucket_id": bucket.id,
                    "file_type": file_type
                }
                S3FileManagement.objects.create(**uploaded_data)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error({'message': str(e)})
                logger.error({'message': S3_FOLDER_MESSAGE['S3_FILE_UPLOAD_FAILED']})
                return Response({'message': S3_FOLDER_MESSAGE['S3_FILE_UPLOAD_FAILED']}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When I upload about 5-10 files at a time, the upload process is no problem, but when I upload > 30 files, there will be some files with 502 - CORS errors. (When > than 30 files, not all errors. For example, file 0-15 uploads normally, file 16 has an error, file 17-25 uploads normally, file 26 uploads an error, file 27-30 uploads normally.)

In settings `python`, I was allows CORS

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    '..{url}..vercel.app',
]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    '..{url}..vercel.app',
]
```

[image: This is the picture I got error.]

Additionaly, the python backend I'm using aapanel. Any more additional settings needed?

FE I used ReactJS and Ant Design

Comment: Maybe your view is erroring out when there are >30 files? django-cors-headers currently [doesn't set the headers on error responses](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers/issues/578).

Comment: When > than 30 files, not all errors. For example, file 0-15 uploads normally, file 16 has an error, file 17-25 uploads normally, file 26 uploads an error, file 27-30 uploads normally.